# Overriding styles antd component on V5

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro, css-in-js

I want to customize the styles of some antd components written in cssinjs.

I created a HOC component to access the theme and override some styles and call it after defining the providers

```
import { useToken, useStyleRegister } from 'antd/es/theme/internal'
import { prefixCls } from 'Src/constants'
import { ReactNode } from 'react'
import { CSSObject } from '@ant-design/cssinjs'
import { GlobalToken } from 'antd/es/theme/interface'



function getStyleButton(token: GlobalToken): CSSObject {
  return {
    [`.${prefixCls}-btn`]: {
      ['&-default']: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent '
      }
    }
  }
}



export const OverloadStyle = (props: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [theme, token, hashId] = useToken()

  useStyleRegister(
    {
      theme,
      token,
      hashId,
      path: ['OverloadStyle']
    },
    () => [
      getStyleButton(token),
    ]
  )
  return <>{props.children}</>
}
```

but there was a problem with style priority

[image: order style]

calling !important is not the best way

[image: style in head]
how to make those styles which I define were below?
Or are there other more convenient ways to extend the standard styles?

[image: live example]
[image]

Comment: Please add a link of reproduction (stackBlitz, sandBox, etc...).

Comment: @WebBrother add example

Answer (score 1):

Using `!important` is not a great long-term approach instead ANTD actually has documentation on how to handle this.

Since the release of V5 they have introduced a configuration context provider to allow you to override styles you need to override.

See documentation: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

Example

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
      token: {
        colorPrimary: '#00b96b',
      },
    }}
  >
    <Button />
</ConfigProvider>
```

To find what you need to override each component has a "Design tokens" section which tells you which variable names are used by the component. For example for the collapse you can see here: https://ant.design/components/collapse#design-token.

Finally, you can choose to either wrap each component in its own context provider and override styles locally or you can put the provider at the root of your app and override everything in one place. Each option has some benefits and downsides so you will need to decide based on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There are no problems with key overrides, everything works fine. The problem is only in overriding css. I have to increase nesting or add !important. I would like to control overrides with the help of the order of initiation of style in html.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `!important` keyword:

```
return {
  [`.ant-btn`]: {
    ["&-default"]: {
      backgroundColor: "red !important"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: calling !important is not the best way((